# What is out-of-band callback?

Tags: asp.net

What is an out-of-band callback?
Is this similar to AJAX? Please explain..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163941.aspx